# New animation on armature runs previous animation

Tags: animation

I have an animation stored under one amature.  I wish to create another animation.  I select the new amature that I want to create the animation on (it is wholly separate from the first amature).  I hit "new" in the action editor.  As soon as I move past the first frame, the object animates with the original animation.

Why is this?  How do I stop this from happening?

ETA - Blender file is here: https://gofile.io/?c=mU1IBA
Reproduce the problem: with the Track Controller armature highlighted (it is when you open the folder), if you press i on the Location Transform to pin the initial position and then move the frame forward, the other armature translocates sideways.  I don't know why.  I don't believe it is connected to anything affected.

Thanks,

A

Video of my issue is here: [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/user100351620/review/345501387/1b3de755f1)

Comment: hard to tell, maybe share your file (at least the armatures)

Comment: @moonboots file shared - thanks.  Comments in original post detailing the issue.

Comment: I also tried clearing ALL parenting.  I then tried to add a new animation on the Track Controller armature, and again it moved the other armature.  I really don't get that.  They're not even linked in the hierarchy.

Comment: Rename the controller bone in the Properties>>Bone tab to don't have the same as any of the another armature.

Comment: @FFeller I did this and it didn't make a difference.  Do I need to reset anything for it to take effect?

Comment: It worked for me in your file, I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @FFeller I've made the changes you said and it hasn't worked.  I've uploaded a video to the original post that shows my issues.  Please help?